# How to print just one column after -sort?

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I am trying to sort the second column of a text file, then print only the sorted second column. My current attempt is printing the entire line after sorting. I am hoping there is a simple fix, or I simply overlooked something.

My attempt: `sort -t\| -k2 dailyUserProcs.YYYY0430`

Comment: It would help to explain what the second column is? Alpha-text, numbers, version numbers, etc...

Comment: `sort -t '|' -k 2,2 | cut -d '|' -f2`?

Comment: It's just letters.

Answer (score 0):

Hacky, inefficient solution:

```
awk '{print $2}' file |sort
```

Comment: It would scale better to large files to reverse that into `sort -k2,2 file | awk '{print $2}'`; that way `sort` can parallelize into multiple threads handling subsets of the file at the same time (having a real, seekable file handle). Granted, I don't know if that behavior actually happens without an explicit `--parallel` option, but structuring the pipeline to put the parallelizable work first preserves the option.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have duplicates in column 2? When you only want unique entries you can gain performance by

```
awk -F'|' '{a[$2]++} END {for (i in a) print i}' dailyUserProcs.YYYY0430 | sort
```